# WPF: DataGrid does not show records unless its ItemsSource property explicitly bound to the list of records

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have the following issue in my WPF application. I have a dedicated area in my Main window where I want to display various user controls, depending on the user's input. One of the UCs I have will allow the user to search the repository for some records. The customer's request is that the UC should contain all records when displayed the first time and only filter the data based on search criteria for subsequent searches. I am using the MVVM patter and I have my views, my models (defined in a separate Business Layer project) and my view-models.
I inject the repository service in my UC's view model, so I can fetch the data any time the user performs a search.

I set the the DataContext of my view to the instance of the view-model I created. Here is an excerpt from the Initialize method of my MainWindowviewModel class:

```
_myUserControlView = new MyUserControlView();
var userControlViewModel = new MyUserControlViewModel(_repositoryService);
_myUserControlView.DataContext = userControlViewModel;
```

The user control view contains a grid that is supposed to display the records fetched by the repo service. When the view-model for my UC view gets built, I can see that the repo service is fetching the correct data. But nothing is displayed in the grid. The XAML contains the proper ItemSource binding for the grid:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyUcDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding MyRepoFetchedList}">
```

However, if I explicitly set the ItemsSource in my Initialize method, the data is properly displayed:

```
_myUserControlView = new MyUserControlView();
var userControlViewModel = new MyUserControlViewModel(_repositoryService);
_myUserControlView.DataContext = userControlViewModel;
_myUserControlView.MyUcDataGrid.ItemsSource = userControlViewModel.MyRepoFetchedList;
```

I was following some courses on PluralSight and none of them had this explicit assignment. For all those working examples, the binding in the XAML was enough.
What am I missing? My models are defined in a BL library, but I do not think that is the case. The samples on PluralSight, more simpler than my solution, would have the models in the same WPF project. The other thing is that the example I saw on PluralSight would fetch the records asynchronously. My code, still in the early development stages, does not. I will change that, but I don't think it is the case. Anyone has any clues why the DataGrid would not display my records unless I bind again the ItemsSource to the proper list in the code?

TIA,
Eddie

Comment: Is `MyRepoFetchedList` a public property? Or does `MyUserControlView` set the `DataContext` property anywhere within it? If neither of those are the cause, then I would recommend using a tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see why the `DataContext` is not being set and inherited correctly in your `Grid`.

Comment: Place `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyRepoFetchedList}"></TextBlock>` outside DataGrid and see. This displayed your MyRepoFetchedList's type. If it is empty, your MyRepoFetchedList not visible. `MyRepoFetchedList` must be `PUBLIC` and must be `PROPERTY`

Comment: Please show definition of `MyRepoFetchedList`, in the view model.

Comment: Thank you both. MyRepoFetchedList was public, but was not a property. As soon as I turned it into a property, it worked. Somehow I missed that essential part.